# Dijkstra's algorithm with Direction in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, dijkstra

I have added all of my nodes and relationships. But an issue is that when using Dijikstra, I don't get it in a single direction:

```
(0)--[PROGRESSED_TO,3812]-->(1)<--[PROGRESSED_TO,3965]--(26)--[PROGRESSED_TO,4932]-->(63) weight:0.07873392808600001
```

As we see we have `A -> B <- C -> D`

Why is my path not just going forward?

My algo is created by:

```
PathFinder dijkstra = dijkstra(Traversal.expanderForAllTypes(), CommonEvaluators.doubleCostEvaluator("length"));
```

Whereby I iterate through paths:
`Iterator<WeightedPath> paths = dijkstra.findAllPaths(node_a, node_b ).iterator();`

Comment: Could you please revise your answer to include more details about your setup as well as the scenario in which you encounter your problem? For instance, what version of Neo4j are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the expander to only go in one particular direction:

```
Traversal.expanderForAllTypes(Direction.OUTGOING);
```

As an aside, if you are using Neo4j 2.0 or greater, you should aim at using traversal components in org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal, rather than the ones from org.neo4j.kernel. The kernel ones are internal code and may change. Something like this:

```
PathExpanders.forDirection(Direction.OUTGOING);
```